# Couldn't inject @Binds Hilt Dependencies in WorkManager using @WorkerInject

Tags: android, android-workmanager, dagger-hilt

I tried to build with the following code in

[Followed the Hilt-WorkManager official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack#workmanager)

**Worker class**

```
class StartJobWorker @WorkerInject constructor(
    @Assisted appContext: Context,
    @Assisted workerParams: WorkerParameters,
    private val startJobUseCase: StartJobUseCase,
) : CoroutineWorker(appContext, workerParams) {

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        val jobId: Long = inputData.getLong(AppConstant.JOB_ID, 0)
        return when (val workResult: WorkResult = startJobUseCase(jobId)) {
            is WorkResult.Success<*> -> Result.success()
            is WorkResult.Failure<*> -> Result.failure()
            WorkResult.Retry -> Result.retry()
        }
    }

}
```

**Hilt Module**

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
abstract class UseCaseModule {

    @ActivityScoped
    @Binds
    abstract fun bindStartJobUseCase(startJobUseCaseImpl: StartJobUseCaseImpl): StartJobUseCase

}
```

**Dependency abstraction**

```
interface StartJobUseCase {
    suspend operator fun invoke(jobId: Long): WorkResult
}
```

**Dependency Implementation**

```
class StartJobUseCaseImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val startJobRepository: StartJobRepository
) : StartJobUseCase {

    override suspend fun invoke(jobId: Long): WorkResult {
        return startJobRepository.startJob(jobId)
    }

}
```

I got the following error message in the compilation.

```
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.example.domain.StartJobUseCase cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
```

Please let me know the solution for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

As EpicPandaForce said, Swapping ActivityComponent with ApplicationComponent and removing @ActivityScoped in UseCaseModule class fixed the issue.

**Hilt Module**

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
abstract class UseCaseModule {

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindStartJobUseCase(startJobUseCaseImpl: StartJobUseCaseImpl): StartJobUseCase

}
```

Comment: The solution was that `ActivityComponent` was swapped out for `ApplicationComponent`. The `provides vs binds` thing is not relevant to the solution.

Comment: You are right my bad. Swapping ActivityComponent with ApplicationComponent fixed the issue